# Browser go back button Confirm Form Resubmission

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form on my page.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='search' />
    <input type='sumit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the submit button on the form, it should run a mysql_query and create a link to the user page.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $add = "city = {'$_POST['search']'}";
}

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE {$add}");
        while($rw=mysql_fetch_object($res)){
        echo "<a href=user.php?id={$rw->user_id}?>{$rw->name}</a>";
        }
```

When I click on the link `user.php?id=3`, it goes to the user page and everything is OK. But I have problem when I click the browser's back-button, on user.php page. Then i have problem back to previous page.
Confirm Form Resubmission.

Comment: This is wide open to SQL injection, look into sanitizing your `$_POST['search']` before using it anywhere in a query!  There's nothing stopping me from searching for `x'; truncate user; '` or something similar ;) to clear out your database.

Comment: This is just an example. I am using mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing users to Refresh browser without the "Confirm Form Resubmission" pop-up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414660/allowing-users-to-refresh-browser-without-the-confirm-form-resubmission-pop-up)

Comment: Not duplicate. I cant refresh page after submiting because  create extension on query.

Answer (score -1):

Correct the following:

```
<input type='sumit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
```

You are writing `type='sumit'` instead of `type='submit'`

Comment: This is just an example. In my code all is typed correctly. Problem is back to previous page. Confirm Form Resubmission

Answer (score -1):

To not display the "*Confirm Form Resubmission*" alert, do you have to change your submission (method) to GET.

```
<form action='' method='GET'>
    <input type='text' name='search' />
    <input type='sumit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>

...

if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $res = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE city='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']) ));
    while($rw=mysql_fetch_object($res)){
      echo "<a href=user.php?id={$rw->user_id}?>{$rw->name}</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I prevent Confirm Form Resubmission?

Comment: Any browser when you send data using POST will ask if you want re-submit that information using back button, or refreshing the page. It`s standards!. So you have to change your approach using, instead of POST, GET!

Answer (score -2):

You should use get method instead of post. Post resubmissions must be confirmed by most browsers.

P.s.: you shouldn't pass the user input into your sql query directly to prevent the risk of sql injections.